# Vagrant up and ssh not working on school network

Tags: vagrant

I'm connected via WiFi to my school's network and when I try to `vagrant up` or `vagrant ssh` I get the following messages:

vagrant up

```
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
```

vagrant ssh

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your school's firewall may be using deep packet inspection (DPI)..

Comment: @oldmud0 actually I just tried at home and the same problem is happening. I'll create a new VM and try.